# Как искать сообщения на Телеграм канале?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Я использую Telethon 1.19.5. Моя задача - получить сообщения на канале.

Код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 123
api_hash = 'api_hash'
username = 'myUsername'
chat = 'news'

with TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash) as tg_client:
  tg_client.start()
  print('Telegram bot initiated!')
  for message in tg_client.iter_messages(chat):
     print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

Выходные данные:

Вопрос: следуя документации написал этот код, в итоге программа ничего не выводит. В чем может быть здесь проблема? Буду благодарен любой помощи, спасибо заранее.

Comment: пробовали указать для `chat` id канала или его "ник" - то что указано в ссылке после t.me/ в вариациях с @ и без?

Comment: @Violet дело в том, что он даже не печатает `print('Telegram bot initiated!')` при старте бота

Comment: Лучшее решение - писать на aiogram